# wrong built-in strings encoding on JSF 1.1 at tomcat under windows

Tags: java, windows, jsf, jakarta-ee, unicode

I'm writing an application using jsf.
My gradle dependencies:

```
    [group: "commons-digester", name: "commons-digester", version: "2.1"],
    [group: "com.sun.facelets", name: "jsf-facelets", version: "1.1.14"],
    [group: "javax.faces", name: "jsf-api", version: "1.2_15"],
    [group: "javax.faces", name: "jsf-impl", version: "1.2_15"],
    [group: "javax.servlet", name: "jstl", version: "1.2"],
    [group: "org.richfaces.framework", name: "richfaces-api", version: "3.3.3.Final"],
    [group: "org.richfaces.framework", name: "richfaces-impl", version: "3.3.3.Final"],
    [group: "org.richfaces.ui", name: "richfaces-ui", version: "3.3.3.Final"],
    [group: "org.apache.poi", name: "poi", version: "3.2-FINAL"],
    [group: "org.primefaces", name: "primefaces", version: "1.1"],
    [group: "net.sf.json-lib", name: "json-lib", version: "2.4"],
    [group: "commons-codec", name: "commons-codec", version: "1.5"],
    [group: "mysql", name: "mysql-connector-java", version: "5.1.17"],
    [group: "org.slf4j", name: "slf4j-api", version: "1.6.2"]
```

My jsp page outputs some text straight from bean, where it stored as String.
When I use cyrillic string from properties - all looks fine.
But when I use cyrillic string from bean field - I got something like

Rich datatable code:

```
        <rich:dataTable value="#{PrintForm.data}" var="invoize" align="center">
            <rich:column colspan="#{invoize[0].colspan}" rowspan="#{invoize[0].rowspan}"
                         rendered="#{invoize[0].rendered}">
                <h:outputText value="#{invoize[0].data}"/>
            </rich:column>
            <rich:column colspan="#{invoize[1].colspan}" rowspan="#{invoize[1].rowspan}"
                         rendered="#{invoize[1].rendered}">
                <h:outputText value="#{invoize[1].data}"/>
            </rich:column>
            <rich:column colspan="#{invoize[2].colspan}" rowspan="#{invoize[2].rowspan}"
                         rendered="#{invoize[2].rendered}">
                <h:outputText value="#{invoize[2].data}"/>
            </rich:column>
            <rich:column colspan="#{invoize[3].colspan}" rowspan="#{invoize[3].rowspan}"
                         rendered="#{invoize[3].rendered}">
                <h:outputText value="#{invoize[3].data}"/>
            </rich:column>
            <rich:column colspan="#{invoize[4].colspan}" rowspan="#{invoize[4].rowspan}"
                         rendered="#{invoize[4].rendered}">
                <h:outputText value="#{invoize[4].data}"/>
            </rich:column>
            <rich:column colspan="#{invoize[5].colspan}" rowspan="#{invoize[5].rowspan}"
                         rendered="#{invoize[5].rendered}">
                <h:outputText value="#{invoize[5].data}"/>
            </rich:column>
        </rich:dataTable>
```

InvoiceBean code sample:

```
this.invoiceData.add(Arrays.asList(
            new TableCellData(1[colspan], 1[rowspan], true[rendered], "[Some cyrillic text]"),
            new TableCellData(4, 1, true, "[Some cyrillic text]"),
            new TableCellData(1, 1, false, ""),
            new TableCellData(1, 1, false, ""),
            new TableCellData(1, 1, false, "")
    ));
```

And on page in table cell I got:

```
Р”РѕРїРѕР»РЅРёС‚РµР»СЊРЅР°СЏ СѓРїР°РєРѕРІРєР°
```

Any ideas, please?

**Update**

printForm.jsp starts with:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="f" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="h" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="rich" uri="http://richfaces.org/rich" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="a4j" uri="http://richfaces.org/a4j" %>
<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8" contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
f:view>
<html>
<head><title><h:outputText value="[Cyrillic Text Displayed Ok]"/></title></head>
<body style="margin: auto; width: 800px;">
<h:form>
    <rich:panel>
        <center>
            <h1>
                [Cyrillic Text Displayed Ok]
            </h1>
        </center>
    </rich:panel>
```

**So, [Cyrillic Text Displayed Ok] is ok, but [Some cyrillic text] is wrong.**

**Notice: it's all ok when tomcat is running under Ubuntu Linux x64, but [Some cyrillic text] is wrong when Tomcat is running under Microsoft Windows 7 x86**

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to top of your JSP.

```
<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
```

Or if you want to apply this on **all** JSPs, add the following entry to your `web.xml`:

```xml
<jsp-config>
    <jsp-property-group>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
        <page-encoding>UTF-8</page-encoding>
    </jsp-property-group>
</jsp-config>
```

#### See also:

- [Unicode - How to get the characters right?](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html)

Comment: Thanks, but doesn`t solve problem - I already have pageEncoding="UTF-8" in jsp. Adding jsp-config to web.xml has no effect.
Updated question.